# Could not find com.android.tools:common:25.2.3

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have set up the environment for compiling a Cordova Android app on my desktop and everything has worked fine. Then I compiled it on my laptop and I can't get it to compile the app.

**I get this error**

```
Could not find com.android.tools:common:25.2.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:25.2.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:25.2.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:25.2.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:25.2.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:dvlib:25.2.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3
```

and this is **my build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

Comment: Share your app level build.gradle, my guess is that you have a different version like 28.0.0

Comment: Watching. I have the same issue, related to adding react-native-image-picker: 

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-image-picker:classpath'.

Comment: Same issue with Cordova..

Comment: Can you guys please try the fixes mentioned in this thread and let us know if any of them work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53677823/391955

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For Cordova Users**

Been struggling with this the whole day. This was happening for fresh cordova android project. Here is how I fixed it:

From your project folder navigate to `platforms/android/cordovaLib` and open up the build.gradle file and replace this line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

with:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

Then open up the build.gradle file from the `platforms/android/`folder and make the above change too. And then replace:

```
 maven {
     url "https://maven.google.com"
 }
```

with:

```
mavenCentral()
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved the problem but it didn't work the first time, I had to change the gradle version from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0 manually in the platforms/android/build.gradle and then it worked

Comment: Hi. In my case this causes to  error - Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0

Comment: Rob, In that case, try adding `maven {  url "https://maven.google.com" }` alongside `mavenCentral()`

Comment: Thanks Towfiq. It also causes an error-  Could not find play-services-tasks-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.8.0).
But after swaping it with jcenter() it works. Here is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987790/could-not-find-play-services-tasks-license-aar-com-google-android-gmsplay-serv

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Someone has removed the 25.2.3 jar/pom from jcenter repository.

I did a temporary fix by using gradle 3.1.4 instead of 2.2.3 and adding google() to the repository as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Still having the same issue. Whats your gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties ?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with react-native-image-picker.  I found a fix on their github as follows, in the build gradle of react-native-image-picker in the node modules folder:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/999